# Can mapleader be Ctrl or Shift?

Tags: leader

Must mapleader be a key with a char?

Can I use Ctrl/Shift/Alt or some other keys which won't type a char in insert mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> are [modifier keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key). They modify another key, when pressed together with it. Vim can't detect them by itself.